# Как передать все значения item в RecycleView?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть recycleview с данными и мне надо передать все данные items в другое активити,как мне это реализовать?

Comment: для этого есть намерение Intent у которого есть особенность передавать данные с помощью put.Extra

Comment: у меня несколько item с разными значениями, вы предлагаете передать только один item.

Comment: Тогда можно внести коррективы в свой адаптер вы же используете его наверника

Comment: Вам нужен Адаптер который будет имеь все данные

Comment: Нужно создать класс наследуясь от BaseAdapter и там задаете все данные и ставиего во View view передачу всех данных

Comment: или может вы уже испоьзуете какието адаптеры и в них есть все знавения

Comment: Активити, которая отображает `RecyclerView` имеет эти данные (вы передавали их в адаптер списка). Воспользуйтесь любым доступным способом коммуникации между активити, чтобы передать их в другую активити - через интент (в зависимости от типа данных возможно потребуется сериализация) , интерфейс-колбэк, шину данных вроде EventBus.

Comment: Спасибо все четко и понятно!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Зачем делать такой костыль как в предыдущем ответе, если любую модель можно сделать сериализуемой (`implements Parcelable`) и передавать всю модель целиком?

Кладем в intent:
`intent.putExtra("parcelable", myParcelables.get(position))`

Берем из intent:
`MyParcelable model = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("parcelable")`

пример реализации:

```
public class Country implements Parcelable {

    private String code;

    private String name;

    private String tag;

    private int limit;

    private String image;

    public Country(JSONParser data) {
        code = data.getString("code");
        name = data.getString("value");
        tag = data.getString("flag");
        image = data.getString("image");
        if (data.contains("limit")) {
            limit = data.getInt("limit") - code.length();
        }
    }

    public Country(Parcel in) {
        code = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();
        tag = in.readString();
        image = in.readString();
        limit = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Country> CREATOR = new Creator<Country>() {
        @Override
        public Country createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Country(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Country[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Country[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(code);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(tag);
        dest.writeString(image);
        dest.writeInt(limit);
    }

    public String getClearCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return "+" + code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public int getLimit() {
        return limit;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```

**P.S.**

Чтобы не словить `BadParcelableException` при передаче между активностями
Parcelable-конструктор должен инициализировать данные в том же порядке, в котором они были записаны в `Parcel` в методе `void writeToParcel(Parcel, int)`

Comment: поставил лайк, но не всегда лучше использовать Parcel... Иногда лучше putExtra, к примеру при г - коде ;)

Answer (score 2):

Самый примитив добавить кликер и передать данные 
Вот примерная реализация

Добавляешь его в слушатель

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourNextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("movie_id_key", movies.get(position).getId); //you can name the keys whatever you like
intent.putExtra("movie_rating_key", movies.get(position).getRating); //note that all these values have to be primitive (i.e boolean, int, double, String, etc.)
intent.putExtra("movie_release_date_key", movies.get(position).getReleaseDate);
startActivity(intent)
```

А это прописываешь в новом Activity:

```
 String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("movie_id_key");
```